# Use Gradle Project Extension Properties In Configuration Phase

Tags: plugins, gradle, checkstyle, build.gradle

When writing a custom Gradle plugin, how is it possible to access the extension properties defined in the consuming `build.gradle` in the custom plugin’s configuration phase?

Please see the following MWE.

**`build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'codechecks'

codechecks {
  checkstyleConfig = '/home/user/checkstyle.xml'
}
```

**`CodechecksPlugin.groovy`**

```
class CodechecksPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project project) {
    project.extensions.create('codechecks', CodechecksPluginExtension)
    project.apply( [ plugin: 'checkstyle' ] )

    project.checkstyle {
      configFile = project.codechecks.checkstyleConfig
    }
  }
}
```

**`CodechecksPluginExtension.groovy`**

```
class CodechecksPluginExtension {
  def checkstyleConfig = 'config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml'
}
```

Wanted behavior: The `checkstyle` plugin uses the configuration file defined in the `build.gradle` `codechecks` extension.

Actual behavior: The default value in the `CodechecksPluginExtension` is being used because the `build.gradle` `codechecks` extension is not yet evaluated.

I already tried putting all *uses* of the `codechecks` extension in the plugins into closures but they won’t expand correctly due to class casting issues at execution phase.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

project.afterEvaluate works for me.

Try:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.checkstyle {
      configFile = project.codechecks.checkstyleConfig
    }
}
```